# ssh tunneling / vpn for video camera streaming

Tags: ssh, video

I want to have access to my video camera which runs a webserver accessible in LAN.

I'm using a 3G modem and my ISP doesn't allow port forwarding, so I can't access the camera from the internet.

I'm thinking at the prerequisites to make this work, but not sure if `ssh` will give me the possibility to access the live video stream.

What I'm thinking:

- a rasperry pi, in the same local network as the camera. The PI will create an ssh tunnel on boot to a VM located in cloud, and accessible from internet.
- VM in cloud configured to redirect all comands to the rasbery PI.
- I would then be able to connect to the VM in cloud via ssh and access the rasbery pi.

Would I be then somehow able to access the camera IP somehow?

Comment: I don't really see the relation to information security here. Just because you use SSH or VPN to tunnel something does not make it implicitly a topic of information security.

Answer (score 1):

Right, you've got the basic idea in your question down, so I'm thinking that you just need general direction in setting up a tunnel and using it to do what you want to.

What I'd personally do is setup a VPN between the raspi, the cloud vm and your own machines (and phone if you want). This way, any system you have which can run the vpn client of choice, will be able to login to the vpn, and access any resources on that network, such as the camera as if it was local.

Setting up a VPN server is far too long for a answer really, however I can point you to a guide that worked for me: [Raspi VPN Router on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64).

---

The other solution, which you've stumbled upon is to setup a SSH Tunnel to the raspi. This will also work, you'd use the raspi as a 'socks proxy' or you can use the ssh tunnel in reverse mode, and basically 'port forward' the camera so it appears to be running locally on the VM.

However this solution doesn't explain how you will then access the VM, you may choose to use a solution over ssh, or maybe setup a web front end which just views the camera as if it was locally on the VM.

For setting this up, you'll need to look into using the raspi as a reverse ssh tunnel, which personally I find is a lot more finicky to setup and can be more confusing if you don't understand exactly what the network is doing.

An ideal guide I've found is: [Raspi Reverse SSH Tunnel](https://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel/)